# Agora Error : stream is closed and cannot be initialized

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

We have inegrated Agora for video call in our platform , but some users are getting this error
"`stream is closed and cannot be initialized`".
Under what circumstances this error may come

Answer (score 2):

I think you haven't added the stream properly and may also be trying to close it at the same time.

Check if you have added the `stream-added` callback after initialising the client and joining the channel.

```js
// Connect New People
client.on('stream-added', function (evt) {
  var stream = evt.stream;
  client.subscribe(stream, function (err) {
  });
});
```

Also check the [documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/start_call_web?platform=Web) to ensure all steps are followed for the video call.

If it still doesn't work, check out [this file](https://github.com/akshatvg/speakOut/blob/master/assets/js/goLive.js) in my [sample app](https://github.com/akshatvg/speakOut) implementing the same.